# Implement superAgent inside my xhrHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

I'm using ES5 and React. My xhrHandler.js is coded my React.creatClass like this:

```
var XhrHandler = React.createClass({
    statics: {

Request: function(request) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = request.url;

        var self = this;

        req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    request.callback(req.response);
                } else {
                    request.errback(status);
                }
            }
        }

        var method = request.method || "GET";

        if (method == "PUT") {
            //send put to api                
        }

        if (method == "DELETE") {
            //send delete to api
        }           

        if (method == "GET") {
            //get from api
        }
    }
},

render: function()
});

module.exports=XhrHandler;
```

The question is, I'm up to use superAgent to my code, but I don't want to call him rather them use my xhrHandler, so I would like to know if I can implement the superAgent inside my xhrHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course you can. Assuming that by superAgent you mean [this library](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent):

```
// import superagent
var agent = require('superagent');
var XhrHandler = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        Request: function(request) {
           var method = request.method || "GET";
           if (method == "GET") {
              // call superagent instead of native XHR:
              agent.get( request.url ).end(function(err, res){
                if (res.ok) {
                  request.callback(res);
                } else {
                  request.errback(res)
                }
              });
           }
           // etc...
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @pawel for the help. I could built an generic agent for all my methods.